# Sterling Db not using custom serialisation

Tags: c#, sterling-db

I am using Sterling DB in a WP7 app and trying to implement a custom serialiser for, hopefully, performance gains.

I'll provide an example (excuse all formatting, trying to compress it to keep it small).  Given a type that inherits `List<string>:`

```
public class TypedList : List<string>
{
    public Guid ObjectId { get; set; }

    public TypedList() {  }
    public TypedList(int count) : base(count) { }
}
```

And it's serialiser:

```
public class TypedListSerializer : Wintellect.Sterling.Serialization.BaseSerializer
{
    public override bool CanSerialize(Type targetType)
    {
        return targetType.Equals(typeof(TypedList));   
    }

    public override object Deserialize(Type type, BinaryReader reader)
    {
        int count = reader.ReadInt32();
        var list = new TypedList(count);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            list.Add(reader.ReadString());

        return list;
    }

    public override void Serialize(object target, BinaryWriter writer)
    {
        var list = (TypedList)target;
        writer.Write(list.Count);

        foreach (string s in list)
            writer.Write(s);
    }
}
```

I register the serialiser with the engine:

```
_engine = new SterlingEngine();
_engine.SterlingDatabase.RegisterSerializer<TypedListSerializer>();
_engine.Activate();
```

Assuming a table of `TypedList` types.  Now when I try to save/load this type on the Sterling instance:

```
// _instance is a class that inherits BaseDatabaseInstance from the Sterling code.
_instance.Save<TypedList>(list);
_instance.Flush();
_instance.Load<TypedList>(g); // g is Guid.
```

It calls into `CanSerialize`, but the `Type` it is given is that of `T` from `List<T>`, the class I inherit from.  If you change `string` to `int`, it tells me the type is an `int`.

**Has anyone else had this problem?  Is this a Sterling issue or one with type information on generics?**

***Update***: as per Marc's suggestion about inheritance, I amended my type to the following:

```
public class TypedList
{
    public Guid ObjectId { get; set; }
    public List<int> Items { get; set; }

    public TypedList() 
    {
        Items = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

What the serializer appears to be doing is checking the properties *of* `TypedList` instead of the type itself.  I'm guessing this is now a fault with how I'm using Sterling.  My table registration line looks like this:

```
protected override List<ITableDefinition> RegisterTables()
{
    return new List<ITableDefinition>
    {
        CreateTableDefinition<TypedList, Guid>(l => l.ObjectId)
    };
}
```

Comment: Just a comment about your tags: Do we really need both `sterling` and `sterling-db` (with the same tag wiki excerpt)?

Comment: @Paulo no, I was planning on one being an alias, however I don't have the privileges for that so I created both for the community moderators to decide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for what it's worth - Sterling expects to be in full control of "top level" entities so it can build the keys, indexes, and other parts that it needs to function. That is why it never calls the custom serializer for the top-level entity (the one you define to have indexes and keys). The custom serializers are meant for properties off of those tables. The fix above is correct because it now sees the list as a property rather than the top level "item" it is trying to serialize.

Comment: Well the fix above isn't strictly true in my case as I'm still trying to custom serialize TypedList, the top level entity.  However, your explanation answers the question.  I suspected this was the case as it can be seen that it's trying to query for serializers for the properties.  Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with that serializer, but it is not uncommon for serializers to "take over" when it comes from lists - using an inbuilt mechanism for representing [n] items, but using the regular pipeline for each item in turn. I *suspect* (purely on a hunch) that this is what is happening here.

Note that as a consequence (and in common with a number of other serializers) it may be inadvisable to have values on the list itself (i.e. `ObjectId`). I would usually use encapsulation rather than inheritance:

```
public class TypedList
{
    public Guid ObjectId { get; set; }

    private readonly List<string> items = new List<string>();
    public List<string> Items { get { return items; } }
}
```

i.e. something that *has* the ObjectId and *has* a list, rather than something that *has* the ObjectId and ***is*** a list.

Comment: good shout on the values on the list, this example comes straight from my first pass at playing with Sterling and isn't going to make it into production :-) I left it the same as it was the example of my issue.

Comment: @Adam of course (\*cough\*) other serialization engines are available ;p

Comment: I made a change based on your suggestion and it appears to have highlighted more observable behaviour - I'm now of the opinion I'm trying to use the serialization providers incorrectly.  Yeah, I've used protobuf-net, but the serialisation mechanism for Sterling isn't pluggable ;-)

Comment: @Adam actually, looking at your sample code I'm fairly confident I *could* plug protobuf-net into the middle of that; but that is probably adding unnecessary complication. Just me rambling...

Comment: the code for all this is available, and the serialisation portion looks straightforward.  Try offering up a patch :-) http://sterling.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/78667#  and if I squint at that code long enough, I might just see why its testing type properties and not the type itself lol!

Comment: Sorry, duff link beforehand... http://sterling.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/78667#1253304

Comment: Not strictly an answer that solved my issues, but you got me looking at the code and the way I was trying to use it so I'm now convinced this particular issue is my own creation.  I'm going to try pulling the code down and run the source to step through and see where it starts querying properties of types.